# Show that $e=Sup\{d_{i}(a_{i},b_{i}): \forall i\geq 1\}$ is a metric that induces the product topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> $\forall i\geq 1$, Let $(X_{i},d_{i})$ be a metric space such that $d_{i}(a,b)\leq1$ for all $a,b\in X_{i}$. Define $e : \prod_{i\geq1}X_{i}\times \prod_{i\geq1}X_{i}\to \mathbb R$ by $e((a_{i})_{i\geq1},(b_{i})_{i\geq1})=Sup\{d_{i}(a_{i},b_{i}) : \forall i\geq1\}$. Prove that $e$ is a metric and that it induces the product topology on $\prod_{i\geq1}X_{i}$.

I have already proved that $e$ is a metric on $\prod_{i\geq1}X_{i}$ and that the topology induced by $e$ ($\mathbb \tau_{e}$) is finer that the product topology ($\tau_{product}$). And I'm having some problems proving the inverse case exactly the point :

The basic open sets of $\tau_{product}$ are $O=\prod_{i=1}^{i=\eta}w_{i}\times \prod_{i\geq \eta +1}X_{i}$ for some $\eta \in \mathbb N$ and $w_{i}$ open in $X_{i}$. If $B_{e}((a_{i})_{i\geq1},\varepsilon)$ is some open ball in $(\prod_{i\geq1}X_{i},e)$. If I want this ball to be open in $\tau_{product}$ then I need for all $(x_{i})_{i\geq1} \in B_{e}((a_{i})_{i\geq1},\varepsilon) $ to find some $O=\prod_{i=1}^{i=\eta}w_{i}\times \prod_{i\geq \eta +1}X_{i}$ such that $(x_{i})_{i\geq1} \in O\subseteq  B_{e}((a_{i})_{i\geq1},\varepsilon)$.But for this to happen we need for all $(y_{i})_{i\geq1}\in O$ to control all the $d_{i}(a_{i},y_{i})$ to be less than $\varepsilon$ so that $Sup\{d_{i}(a_{i},y_{i}): \forall i\geq 1\}$ can be less than $\varepsilon$. Now we can do that for finite $d_{i}(a_{i},y_{i})$ ( by the choice of $O$), but how do we control the remaining infinite $d_{i}(a_{i},y_{i})$ ?

Comment: The metric topology is strictly finer than the metric topology. This is a well-known fact (see the uniform metric on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ which is disconnected while the product topology is connected )

Comment: So you cannot prove the other inclusion as it is wrong.

Comment: Do you mean the product topology is finer than the Sup-metric topology ? .. the exercice is asking me to show that this Sup-metric is topologicaly equivalente to the metric $\sum_{i\geq1}d_{i}(a_{i}),b_{i})\times 2^{-i}$ , and the last induces the product topology. @HennoBrandsma

Comment: The product topology is coarser. This sup metric is **not** equivalent to the sum metric you defined.

Comment: thank you Mr@HennoBrandsma I've been trying for 2 days to prove the statement .. the exercice is already wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exercise is wrong. E.g. taking $X_i=\{0,1\}$ in the discrete metric, then $e$ induces the discrete topology on the product while the product topology is homeomorphic to the standard Cantor set (compact and all open sets are infinite, so not discrete at all).